# Why does Spring's `AuthenticationWebFilter` have it's own matcher for checking if a request needs authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

As the title says; `AuthenticationWebFilter` has it's own set of matchers to determine if a request needs authentication. This seems to work against spring security's way of doing things.

If an endpoint is set in spring securty config to `.permitAll()` it would also have to be excluded in the `AuthenticationWebFilter`, why doesn't the filter just let the request through and let the rest of spring security handle it?

EDIT: To reframe my question in response [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68171024/645519) by Steve Riesenberg:

Why does `AuthenticationWebFilter`, an authentication filter, control access to resources? Shouldn't that be handled by the authorization filters?

EDIT: I just figured out that the filter actually doesn't block access when there is not authentication, only when verification fails, which makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that my confusion was due to a misunderstanding of how `AuthenticationWebFilter` works. My understanding was that it would block any request not sucessfully authenticated, but it turns out it only blocks request for which authentication failed. Requests with no authentication at all are let through.

This actually makes sense.

I didn't look too closely at this filter since I remembered that a similar servlet filter works this way, `AbstractAuthenticationFilter` or something I think. I'm still pretty sure that one works that way, and I still wonder why, but as I'm not sure I will close this question by answering it myself. If it comes up in the future I might post another question.

My thanks to the people who answered!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question lies in an understanding of filter ordering and purpose within Spring Security. Your question specifically references `AuthenticationWebFilter`, which is used in reactive applications. The Spring Security docs have a [comprehensive list of filters in order](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-security-filters) for servlet applications, but you can refer to the [SecurityWebFiltersOrder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/web/server/SecurityWebFiltersOrder.java) enumeration for a similar ordering in reactive applications.

In both cases, you can see that "authorization" (`FilterSecurityInterceptor` in servlet, `AuthorizationWebFilter` in reactive) is effectively the last filter in the list. Therefore, if you set a route to `.permitAll()` in `http.authorizeExchange()`, you are instructing the authorization manager to allow that request, assuming it passes all other filters in the filter chain. By setting the matcher in `AuthenticationWebFilter` to the same route, you are asking *that* filter to attempt authentication for that route, which will terminate processing and never reach the authorization step. Only authorized requests will reach your application code, but some requests can be processed by the filter chain prior to (and instead of) your application needing to handle them.

Put simply, authentication is attempted/handled prior to authorization.

Comment: As I asked in my edit; why does the authentication filter control access to resources? Should that not be a job for the authorization filters?